# Proving that determinant is zero

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, matrix-rank

Let $A,B \in M_3(\mathbb{C})$ such that $(AB)^2 = A^2B^2$ and $(BA)^2 = B^2A^2$. Prove that $\det(AB-BA) = 0$.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I tried to prove that rank(AB - BA) is less than 3.

Comment: And this could work perhaps like [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2581210/prove-that-detab-ba-0).

Comment: I don’t think so. If C = AB - BA, we get from the conditions that ACB = 0 = BCA. I don’t see how to go on from here. Maybe the rank doesn’t matter at all...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hints.* Let $C=AB-BA$. The given conditions imply that $ACB=0$ and $BCA=0$. We don't need both of them. One --- say, $ACB=0$ --- is enough:

- If at least one of $A$ or $B$ has rank $\le1$, argue that $\operatorname{rank}(C)=\operatorname{rank}(AB-BA)\le2$.
- If $\operatorname{rank}(A),\operatorname{rank}(B)\ge2$, then $\operatorname{rank}(CB)\ge2$ when $C$ is non-singular. Now consider [Sylvester's rank inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_(linear_algebra)#Properties) $
  \operatorname{rank}(A)+\operatorname{rank}(CB)-3\le\operatorname{rank}(ACB)$.